# Want to read xml file from published artifacts in azure devops build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, build-pipeline

I am using the azure-DevOps build pipeline to run & publish the postman Newman report as pipeline artifacts.
my pipeline does publish pipeline artifacts (HTML-reports of postman and also gives Newman report in XML files).

My requirement is that using azure-DevOps API I want to read the XML file.
& this API I have to call from my program (nodeJs/Python).

Any idea how? Thanks in Advance
Note: I see ADO is still working on fileId (not sure how to get fileID)
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/issues/381

Comment: Did you get a chance to try out below workaround? how did it go?

Comment: Thanks a lot  Levi Lu-MSFT. This is really helpful for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The artifact published in azure pipeline provides dowload url to get the files. You can get the download url directly from the build summary portal. See below:

Go the published artifacts-->Click the `3dots` of the file you want to download

[image]

You can call the download url directly to read the xml file in your code. See below example in powershell script:

```
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/resources/Containers/{containerId}/{artifactName}?itemPath=artifactName%2Fbuild.xml"

$PAT="Personal access token"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)"))

$xmlContent = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method get
```

If you donot want to get the download url from the UI portal. You can call [Artifacts - Get Artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get%20artifact?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get the container id. Then you can get the download url for the xml file after you get the container id.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/artifacts?artifactName={artifactName}&api-version=6.0
```

See below example result from above rest api.

[image]

Download url:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/resources/Containers/{containerId}/{artifactName}?itemPath={artifactName}%2F{xmlfileName.xml}
```